# How can I add an auto incremental integer beside my username string?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to firebase so, please bear with me. I am making a registration using firebase realtime database in android studio. What I want to do is that when the user enters her firstname and lastname, the system will set the username for them by taking the first character of the firstname and concatenate it with the lastname.

Example:
Name: John Smith
Username: jsmith

There are cases that there would be a duplication for the username because there are so many names that starts with J with the lastname Smith. So what I want is to add an integer if the username already exist.

jsmith, jsmith1, jsmith2, etc...

I know I needed to add a loop but I just don't know how to construct it. Here is my code:

```
public void insertAccount(){
        acctstatus.setText("Active");
        accttype.setText("Employee");
        final String status = acctstatus.getText().toString();
        final String type = accttype.getText().toString();
        final String lname = empLname.getText().toString();
        final String fname = empFname.getText().toString();
        final String newfname = fname.substring(0,1).toLowerCase();
        final String newuname = newfname+lname.toLowerCase();

//        empuname.setText(newuname);
//        final String uname = empuname.getText().toString();
//        String passw = UUID.randomUUID().toString().substring(0,5);
//        emppassw.setText(passw);
//        String newpassw = emppassw.getText().toString();
        String newpassw = newuname;

        //
        final int num = 0;

        accountFirebaseReference.orderByChild("acct_uname").equalTo(newuname)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            String username = newuname+num+1;
                            empuname.setText(username);
                            final String acctuname = empuname.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username: "+acctuname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }else{
                            String username = newuname;
                            empuname.setText(username);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username: "+empuname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    final String acctuname = empuname.getText().toString();
                    final String acctpassw = empuname.getText().toString();

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

        //addAccount(newuname, newpassw, type, status);

    }
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

merely a suggestion. If a username exists, add a `01`, like this `jDoe01`,`jDoe02`.... then `jDoe011`, etc.

Then, if a document exists, get the index of that zero, (it will always exist)

you can use something like `int index = yourUserNameFromFirebase.indexOf('0');`

then, you can use that index to get the number from the document, through doing a substring:

```
String numberValue = yourUserNameFromFirebase.substring(index);
int countOfDuplicateNames = Integer.valueOf(numberValue);
```

then, you can simply increment `countOfDuplicateNames` and make a new user, just remember to always ensure that the `0` is there, as this is the only way to get a reference to the number.

to pseudo code it, your new username will be something like this:

```
initial + surname + '0' + countOfDuplicateNames+1
```

---

**Note**

Sorry this answer does not cater for starting at an index of `1` :D

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this :) Any idea on how to do this using loop?

Comment: @no_profile to do it with a loop is going to be pretty bad, you'll be making a ton of firebase calls

Comment: if you do it with a loop, you're going to be making a service call every single time a user already exists. if you get to jdoe99, you'll have done close to 100 service calls just to achieve this. the amount of firebase calls you have are limited per month for free plans, then you have to start paying